# Block ui when Loading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery-blockui

i want to block my ui until values in my drop down not loaded
my js file code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Load All Toll Plazas
    FillInCascadeDropdown({ userType: -1 }, "#ddlTollPlazas", "/Home/GetTollPlazas/" + -1);
}

function FillInCascadeDropdown(map, dropdown, action) {
    $(dropdown).empty();
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>' });
    $.post(action, map, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            $(dropdown).append("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>");
        });
    }, "json");
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

above code not working on page load.

Comment: What exactly isn't working. Does it seem to block very quickly then go away?

Comment: yes block very quickly and then go away

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is you are unblocking as soon as you call blockUI. You need to move the unblock call to a "Success" callback function. The concept of Callbacks are a little tricky. Basically this is the code that runs once the post is successful. I'm sure you've seen this page but refer to the [jQuery post page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to see where you need to put your callback and [here](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) to learn more about callbacks if you need to. Good luck!

Here is how it should look:

```
function FillInCascadeDropdown(map, dropdown, action) {
    $(dropdown).empty();
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>' });
    $.post(action, map, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            $(dropdown).append("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>");
        });

        $.unblockUI();
    }, "json");
```

Comment: could you suggest me to where i can write unblockui() in above code

Comment: i wrote the same not working on page load means ui blocks and then unblocks immediately

Comment: Strange. So you only have 1 call to unblockUI() on the whole page?